# retrieve a field value from a document using mongodb driver for c++

Tags: c++, mongodb

i'm trying to get a field value from a list of documents of a mongodb collection using mongodb driver-c++ but it seems not working when i add this line :

```
  int val = doc["field2"].Int();
```

Otherwise it's working fine but i don't want to return all the content of the doc,

```
mongocxx::cursor cursor = test_collection.find(document{} << "field1" << "value" << finalize);
for(auto doc : cursor) {
    int val = doc["field2"].Int();
    i++;
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << "\n";
}
return ( 0 );
```

Comment: Why do you think there is an `Int` method on `document::element`? There isn't. Try `get_int32` instead. Note that the `get_int32` method returns a boxed integer, where the box is of type `b_int32`, so you need to access `.value` within that boxed result.